# My command line keeps saying that I don't have matplotlib installed. I've tried everything that I saw on Stack Overflow

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, module, package, version

Here is the code that I used:

```
import math 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The error message was:

```
no module named 'matplotlib'
```

I have tried:

```
pip install matplotlib
python3 install mat plotlib
```

Tried updating Anaconda Navigator to the latest version.

Tried uninstalling and reinstalling Python 3.10.5

Tried using Visual Studio Code and individual Python files (I'll try Jupyter too).

```
conda update --all
```

`python - version` says that I have Python version 3.6.13

After all of that, I still get the same error that there is no module named matplotlib

Comment: Create a virtual environment with `conda` using Python 3.10, activate it, then install `matplotlib` from there.

Comment: Are you working in a python virtual environment? If so, are you sure the environment is activated correctly (if applicable).

Comment: Since you're using conda and pip simultaneously, sometimes conda does not find the pip installed packages for whatever reason. Though you probably want to stick to one package handler, using `conda install matplotlib` instead of pip might be a temporary (but in the long term inadvisable) fix. Otherwise the above comments on using the environments are very much the preferred way to go.

You also have a typo and an error in your second install method:  `python3 install mat plotlib` should read `python3 -m pip install matplotlib`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was that I had never actually attempted to access matplotlib outside of Jupyter Notebooks. I was only meant to access it inside of Jupyter. I created a virtual environment and that didn't work. I also did conda install matplotlib and that destroyed my Python install and I had to reinstall everything.